# c++11 get string length in compile time by constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

```
#include <stdio.h>

constexpr size_t constLength(const char* str)
{
    return (*str == 0) ? 0 : constLength(str + 1) + 1;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    const char* p = "1234567";
    size_t i = constLength(p);
    printf(p);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Hi,all
    I want to get the length of a string in compile-time.So i wrote the code above.But in disassembly code i found 'constLength' function that named sub_401000 below will lead run-time overhead for computting the length of string.Is there something wrong?(Visual Studio 2015 Preview,release with Maximize Speed (/O2) optimization)

```
int __cdecl sub_401010()
{
    int v0; // esi@1

    v0 = sub_401000("234567") + 1;
    sub_401040(&unk_402130);
    sub_401040("%d");
     return 0;
}

int __thiscall sub_401000(void *this)
{
  int result; // eax@2

  if ( *(_BYTE *)this )
    result = sub_401000((char *)this + 1) + 1;
  else
    result = 0;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What optimization settings did you use, and with which compiler and version? Also, what happens if you use `constexpr const char * p = "1234567";` instead? (The issue may arise because `p` is not itself `constexpr` and so the compiler defers evaluation of `constLength(p)` until runtime.)

Comment: I have tried.But it also lead run-time overhead.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour A `constexpr` function *may* be evaluated at compile time if its arguments are constant expressions. The only way to *guarantee* that it will be evaluated at compile time is to perform the evaluation in a context that requires a constant expression.

Comment: @Casey hmmm, I guess it is too much of an assumption that people will actually follow the link the get context, at least that was my assumption but I can see how without context it is misleading, will remove.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does changing to constexpr size_t constLength( const char* const str) change anything?

Answer (score 7):

A `constexpr` function can only be evaluated at compile time when called with arguments that are compile-time constants. Although the value of `p` can be determined by static analysis (it doesn't change between initialization and evaluation), it's not a constant expression per the standard definition.

Try this:

```
constexpr const char* p = "1234567";
```

Also, you can guarantee that an initialization is doable without runtime overhead by declaring the initialized variable as `constexpr`:

```
constexpr size_t i = constLength(p);
```

Comment: 1.I tried constexpr const char* p = "1234567".But i got the same disassembly code like the first time.2.I tried constexpr size_t i = constLength("1234567")then got a compile error:Severity Description Project File Line
Error error C2127: 'i': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression

Comment: @LeonhartSquall That sounds suspiciously like a compiler bug then.

Comment: @LeonhartSquall [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0650b8eb11a6859)

Answer (score 5):

In C++17, you can use [std::char_traits::length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length)

```
constexpr auto l = std::char_traits<char>::length("123");//string("123").length();
cout << l;
```

Answer (score 0):

To force evaluation at compile time, there are a couple tricks.
First, you can use the value in an enum.  But, that pollutes your namespace with "junk" enumerations.

You could also use a simple template to force evaluation at compile-time.  See [static_eval.h](https://github.com/henrygab/UtilHeaders/blob/43830e77fda5b97aa37acac02b5af8198e23f281/src/static_eval.h#L48-L52).  The template is quite small:

```
template<typename T, T V>
struct static_eval
{
    static constexpr T value = V;
};
```

You would then use that template with your above code similar to the following:

```
// size_t i = constLength(p);
size_t i = static_eval<size_t, constLength(p)>::value;
```

This will force compile-time evaluation, or force a compile-time error if the expression does not evaluate to a constexpr.

Comment: Your `static_eval` has an exact standard equivalent: `std::integral_constant`.

Comment: I never realized that!  You are correct, the above is a subset of `std::integral_constant`.  Of course, especially in some IoT focused build environments, the `std` namespace isn't available, so there's still value in a stand-alone option.