# Is possible create QString at compile time?

Tags: c++, qt, constexpr, compile-time

Consider below code:

```cpp
static constexpr QString FOO = QStringLiteral("foo"); // erro compile , because QString has not default destructor.
```

How I can create QString at compile time!? is it possible to create QString at compile time?

Comment: [Qt vs constexpr string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201976/qt-vs-constexpr-string-literal)

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/text/qstring.h.html#QLatin1String
1-QLatin1String has not virtual  destructor 
2- I won't write more class because I want reduce overhead , this create compexity ... (maybe not now )
@DrewDormann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt 6.2 you can use the new u"my string"_qs syntax.  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#operator-22-22_qs

Comment: I didnt switch on Qt6 , but thx I didnt know that !

Answer (score 2):

Before `Qt6` you can use:

```
constexpr QStringView FOO = u"foo";
```